# Convert a string to simple array

Tags: php, arrays, string, type-conversion

I am passing some data to a php page. I have a string data type which i need converted into an array. I have the below code:

```
$args = json_decode($form_update_args,true);
```

The value of $form_update_args is this `$form_update_args = ["update","provider","jghjghjhhh",["folder_76248"]]`
So I need that string to be turned into an array so that it can be used liked so:

```
$field_to_update = $args[1];
$myvalue = $args[2];
$selection = $args[3];
```

However at the moment if you print $args after json_decode it is just empty, no value in there. printing $form_update_args brings back the text above.

What am I missing here?

edit: this is not the same as the posted example as his string looks completely different.

Comment: `$form_update_args` is actually not a string, but an array

Comment: Either @Cid is right, or the code works fine: https://3v4l.org/pG0VC

Comment: strange, when i used gettype() it returned string. the data is actually coming from a http request so is it broken maybe? here : https://gyazo.com/2766d1abfb346d48ff1cc12df323b226

Comment: what is the result of `var_dump($form_update_args);` ?